# jgroups udp.xml example no mcast

Tags: jgroups

```
I am using jgroups with the default udp.xml to connect ApplicationA to Matlab.  My problem is I run Matlab/ApplicationA on multiple machines as follows:
HOST1:  running Matlab and running ApplicationA
HOST2:  running Matlab and running ApplicationA

Because of the multicast HOST1 Matlab/AppA establishes connections with HOST2 Matlab/AppA.   I want to limit Matlab and AppA to only establishing connections on the host it is running, this sounds do able with the udp.xml but I cannot get it right.
```

Can someone show me a udp.xml set up to not use multicast and only establish connections on the host it is running on?  NOTE:  I can modify the udp.xml with each run but would prefer it to be generic and work on any host w/o having to modify the udp.xml with specific host names.

```
<!--
  Default stack using IP multicasting. It is similar to the "udp"
  stack in stacks.xml, but doesn't use streaming state transfer and flushing
  author: Bela Ban
-->

<config xmlns="urn:org:jgroups"`enter code here`
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="urn:org:jgroupshttp://www.jgroups.org/schema/jgroups.xsd">
    <UDP
         mcast_port="${jgroups.udp.mcast_port:45588}"
         ip_mcast="false"
         ip_ttl="0"
         tos="8"
         ucast_recv_buf_size="5M"
         ucast_send_buf_size="5M"
         mcast_recv_buf_size="5M"
         mcast_send_buf_size="5M"
         max_bundle_size="64K"
         enable_diagnostics="true"
         thread_naming_pattern="cl"

         thread_pool.min_threads="0"
         thread_pool.max_threads="20"
         thread_pool.keep_alive_time="30000"/>

    <PING />
    <MERGE3 max_interval="30000"
            min_interval="10000"/>
    <FD_SOCK/>
    <FD_ALL/>
    <VERIFY_SUSPECT timeout="1500"  />
    <BARRIER />
    <pbcast.NAKACK2 xmit_interval="500"
                    xmit_table_num_rows="100"
                    xmit_table_msgs_per_row="2000"
                    xmit_table_max_compaction_time="30000"
                    use_mcast_xmit="false"
                    discard_delivered_msgs="true"/>
    <UNICAST3 xmit_interval="500"
              xmit_table_num_rows="100"
              xmit_table_msgs_per_row="2000"
              xmit_table_max_compaction_time="60000"
              conn_expiry_timeout="0"/>
    <pbcast.STABLE desired_avg_gossip="50000"
                   max_bytes="4M"/>
    <pbcast.GMS print_local_addr="true" join_timeout="2000"
                view_bundling="true"/>
    <UFC max_credits="2M"
         min_threshold="0.4"/>
    <MFC max_credits="2M"
         min_threshold="0.4"/>
    <FRAG2 frag_size="60K"  />
    <RSVP resend_interval="2000" timeout="10000"/>
    <pbcast.STATE_TRANSFER />
    <!-- pbcast.FLUSH  /-->
</config>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's multiple ways of achieving this:

- Set `mcast_addr` and `mcast_port` to different values for each deployment, to separate your clusters. You can do this via system properties, e.g. `mcast_addr=${my-mcast-addr:232.1.1.1}`, then use -Dmy-mcast-addr=x.x.x.x, which will override the default
- Set `ip_ttl` to 0 in `UDP`. This will prevent IP multicast packets from leaving the local box
- Bind to the loopback interface, e.g. by setting (in `UDP`): `bind_addr=loopback`

Comment: Thanks so much.  So is each bullet above independent of the others?   Do I need to set the ip_mcast flag?   The "ip_ttl" sounds like the simpliest change.     Note I had tried the mcast addr change but I was getting jgroup errors when I tried that approach.   I wasn't sure where the bind_addr needed to go.  One additional note, I had to have IT change firewall settings due to the multicast, if I can modify this file such that firewall settings do not have to be changed that would also be perferrable.

Comment: Yes, pick either one of the bullet items. No, as another item, you could set `ip_mcast` to false, but then you'd have to change `PING` into some other discovery protocol, e.g. `MPING`. You can always use `TCP` to not change the firewall rules, but then use a discovery protocol such as `TCPPING` or `FILE_PING` etc...